# Complex Derivative: $\frac{d}{dz} (z+\overline{z} -z^3+z\overline{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

How can I compute the following complex derivative

$$\frac{d}{dz} (z+\overline{z} -z^3+z\overline{z})$$

I know that $\frac{d}{dz} (z\overline{z})=z$ but not sure about the above.

Original problem:

1. $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}(z+\bar{z}-z^3+z\bar{z})$.
2. $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}((z+\bar{z}+16z^8-\bar{z})(-z^4+z^7))$

Comment: You are supposed to evaluate the Partial derivative with respect to $z$ and treat $\bar z$ as independent from $z$.  Can you proceed?

Comment: Oh! so would it be 3z^2+z

Comment: Not quite.  It is $$1-3z^2+\bar z$$But what you wrote does not match the problem in the attached image.  For $(i)$ it is $1+z$

Comment: What was in your image is the derivative with respect to z-bar, not with respect to z. Those will give different results for the $-z^3$ term in particular, so please clarify which one you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I am so confused. There is no "Complex Derivative" page in Wikipedia but I found it in Mathworld: ["Complex Derivative"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDerivative.html).

Let's try to understand this: $\frac{d}{dz}(z\bar z)$. The function is $f(z)=x^2+y^2$ so, $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $v(x,y)=0.$ Then $u_x=2x\neq v_y=0$ and $u_y=2y\neq-v_x=0$. So, $f(z)$ is not complex differentiable and has no complex derivative, except at the origin.

Similarly, $\frac{d}{dz}(z+\bar z-z^3+z\bar z)$ does not exist on any open region of the complex plane.